# Angular routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to append form post data to current url as parameters by using `$location.path`. However, It will reload the current page and not adding those parameters. I figure its `$routeProvider` issue where I have

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
     templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
     controller: 'MainCtrl',
     reloadOnSearch: false,
  })
  .otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

So my question is: is there anyway I can append parameters to my current url without refresh the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, what do you want to do more exactly?

Comment: I am trying to filter my products and append from form post values to current url. So when user hits that url it will direct to the search result instead do the filter again. Something like this site. http://www.zaptravel.com/

Comment: so I have this function   
$http.jsonp($scope.service).success(function(data) {} 
I want to append my filter parameters when success is called
thanks

Comment: OK, so the logic with this kind of behavior is like this. You make a search, the search terms are passed to a service that makes an actual search, the service returns an array with the responses, you print that array, you format your array in html with links that lead to your desired route /:id of the clicked element. So far so good, now on the new page that is loaded, the controller there will take your :id or :whatever paramater and display that content to you. this is the Angular way. i'll post a fiddle in a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I am new to angularjs. Thank you for your help, appreciated it

Comment: Here it is, it is not exactly what you are looking for but it describes the workflow: http://jsfiddle.net/ec86x/ Please read the comments there. You should also read some tutorials http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/write-app-angularjs  like this basic one to understand the principles first. Then you can feel good when looking at code and understanding it :). Like I did :))

Comment: ya I will need to read more tutorials. Thanks